# Matlab, Eclipse CDT and C++ interaction: specific error with mxCreateNumericMatrix

Tags: c++, matlab, eclipse-cdt

As stated above, I use the Matlab engine in combination with Eclipse CDT and C++. When compiling my code, everything works fine. Eclipse just keeps buggin me with a Error-Tooltip stating

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
mxArray_tag * mxCreateNumericMatrix_730(?, ?, enum {matrix.h:6580}, enum {matrix.h:7366})
'
```

Like I said - everything compiles just fine. Has anybody faced similar problems?

---

EDIT: the bad line of code goes:

```cpp
mxArray *result = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
```

which results in (literally) bugging me with the following tooltip:

[image]

Comment: show us please the line of code where it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research the problem seems to be the **CODAN indexer** used by Eclipse CDT. Manually rebuilding the index via `Eclipse > Preferences > C/C++ > Indexer` and ensuring, that the indexer is properly activated (which it was in my case) and then pressing **apply** starts the index-rebuilding process. After this was done (which took about 10 seconds) the problem had vanished.

---

@Nzbuu: thank you for your idea - actually I tried that one, too - explicitly casting to mwSize which changed nothing. I checked also the enums, which were perfectly ok. The problem was - as stated above - the inde

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. You could try casting the `1`'s to `mwSize`.